# Is there a way of disabling Eclipse from moving a folder into another one dragging drop?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

There is any way for disabling Eclipse feature that allows user moving folders by dragging? It can leads to terrible mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable this by going to

```
windows -> preferences -> general -> workspace -> linkedResources
```

and select prompt instead of copy